# Change datatype in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe(**input_dataframe**), whose all columns have datatype as String, I have another dataframe(**output_dataframe**) which has column names same as **input_dataframe**. I need to cast columns of **input_dataframe** based on the datatype of **output_dataframe**. I have written below code for the same:

```
code should be generic
```

I am not able to tackle it for Decimal Datatype, as Decimal datatypes are like decimal(x,y). Is there way to cast values for decimal datatype. Also is there any other efficient way to achieve this solution?

Comment: this is working code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried with just two datatypes including decimal type. pls check with your dataframes,

```
>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- col1: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: decimal(10,0) (nullable = true)

>>> df1.printSchema()
root
 |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: string (nullable = true)

>>> df_schema = {field.name:field.dataType for field in df.schema.fields}
>>> dfSchema
{'col2': DecimalType(10,0), 'col1': IntegerType}

>>> df1_cols = df1.columns
>>> df1_cols
['col1', 'col2']

>>> for f in df1_cols:
        df1 = df1.withColumn(f,df1[f].cast(df_schema[f]))

>>> df1.printSchema()
root
 |-- col1: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: decimal(10,0) (nullable = true)
```